# Corona SDK Level: Can't integrate my level into Storyboard - Assertion Failed error

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I hope someone can help me because this problem has been driving me crazy the last few days. So I just started with corona - made a few tutorials and really having fun discovering the possibilities. 
Problem: I want to integrate a simple game into a storyboard. I somehonw can't manage to find the right combination and always get this error pop up.

```
File: assertion failed!
Assertion failed!
stack traceback:
[C]: ?
[C]: in function 'assert'
?: in function 'get0rCreateTable'
?: in function 'addEventListener'
?: in function 'addEventListener'
...ik/Desktop/_DummyProjekt2/Fruit Fliesv10/level01.lua:51: in function
<. . . ik/Desktop/_DummyProjekt2/ Fruit Fliesv10/level0l. lua:44>
?: in function 'dispatchEvent'
?: in function <?:1096>
(tail call): ?
?: in function <?:466>
?: in function <?:218>
```

It's probably a rookie mistake, but I have been stuck for a few days now and definitely need some help. I've gone thru most of the tutorials and documentation I could find with no luck. So any help would be greately welcome :) So this is my level 1

---

```
local storyboard = require( "storyboard" )
local scene = storyboard.newScene()

local widget = require ("widget")
local playfile = require ("play")



function scene:createScene(event)


local screenGroup = self.view
local spawnEnemy
local gameTitle
local scoreTxt
local score = 0
local hitBowl
local planet
local speedBump = 0



background = display.newImage("images/background.png")
background.y = centerY
background.x = centerX


bowl = display.newImage("images/bowl2.png")
bowl.x = centerX
bowl.y = centerY


scoreTxt = display.newText( "Score: 0", 0, 0, "orange juice", 22 )
scoreTxt.x = centerX
scoreTxt.y = 10
scoreTxt:setFillColor(1,1,1)
scoreTxt.y = 255

end





function scene:enterScene(event)




enemypics = {"images/blue.png","images/pink.png", "images/green.png"}
enemy = display.newImage(enemypics[math.random (#enemypics)])
enemy:addEventListener ( "tap", shipSmash )
    if math.random(2) == 1 then
    enemy.x = math.random ( -100, -10 )
else
    enemy.x = math.random ( display.contentWidth + 10, display.contentWidth + 100 )
    enemy.xScale = -1
end
enemy.y = math.random (display.contentHeight)
enemy.trans = transition.to ( enemy, { x=centerX, y=centerY, time=math.random(2500-speedBump, 4500-speedBump), onComplete=hitBowl } )
speedBump = speedBump + 50

end



function startGame()
text = display.newText( "Tap here to start. Protect the Fruit Bowl!", 0, 0, "orange juice", 24 )
text.x = centerX
text.y = display.contentHeight - 30
text:setFillColor(0, 0, 0)
 local function goAway(event)
display.remove(event.target)
    text = nil
    display.remove(gameTitle)
     spawnEnemy()
     scoreTxt.alpha = 1
     scoreTxt.text = "Score: 0"
     score = 0
     bowl.numHits = 10
    bowl.alpha = 1
     speedBump = 0
 end
text:addEventListener ( "tap", goAway )
end



local function bowlDamage()
    bowl.numHits = bowl.numHits - 2
    bowl.alpha = bowl.numHits / 10
    if bowl.numHits < 2 then
    bowl.alpha = 0
    timer.performWithDelay ( 1000, startGame )
    --audio.play ( sndLose )
else
    local function goAway(obj)
        bowl.xScale = 1
        bowl.yScale = 1
        bowl.alpha = bowl.numHits / 10
    end
    transition.to ( bowl, { time=200, xScale=1.2, yScale=1.2, alpha=1, onComplete=goAway} )
end
end

function hitBowl(obj)

display.remove( obj )
bowlDamage()
--audio.play(sndBlast)
if bowl.numHits > 1 then
    spawnEnemy()
end
end


local function shipSmash(event)
local obj = event.target
display.remove( obj )
--audio.play(sndKill)
transition.cancel ( event.target.trans )
score = score + 5
scoreTxt.text = "Score: " .. score
spawnEnemy()

end



function scene:exitScene(event)

end


function scene:destroyScene(event)

end

scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So LUA is fun in lots of regards and this is one you'll learn quickly.  So I only think this might be the problem, if not it could lead you on the correct trail.

In your top error message you'll see that it gives you this:

`...ik/Desktop/_DummyProjekt2/Fruit Fliesv10/level01.lua:51: in function`

That `level01.lua:51` signifies a line number, so line 51 (or around there).  And the lines above it in the error mention addEventListener.  Those two things are our clues.

Here's some code from around there:

```
enemy = display.newImage(enemypics[math.random (#enemypics)])
enemy:addEventListener ( "tap", shipSmash )
    if math.random(2) == 1 then
```

Looks like there's an addEventListener there, one parameter is a string, the other is a function.  Where is that function?  It's on line `117` which is after line `51` which is most likely the problem.  In LUA (and some other languages) you have to declare things in order.  So you could do two things.  You could move the `shipSmash` function up above line `51` or you could forward declare that variable.  So up in the top part of your file you could do `local shipSmash`.  This assures line `51` that that name exists (what it's trying to check) and then you can declare it later (sometimes I do this for code structure).

Hopefully that helps.  I've been using LUA/Corona SDK since about July, I'm still getting used to a lot of the small things like this that I've spent hours ripping my hair out over.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it and it worked! Got an other error pop up after that (unrelated) but I managed to figure out that one :) thanks a lot!